# Is there a way to remove a directory from a dynamic URL using Vue-Router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I've build a vue.js web app for an insurance brokerage where every agent has their own website that is generated from their profiles.

This is what the link looks like in my vue-router index file"

```
{
  path: '/agents/:id',
  name: 'AgentSite',
  component: AgentSite
},
```

Everything works great EXCEPT that the urls are getting too long to fit on some business cards. I would like to change the URLs to be like this:

```
{
  path: '/:id',
  name: 'AgentSite',
  component: AgentSite
},
```

However, then every other bit of dynamic content in the app loads our agent website template (AgentSite). Quotes, Clients, Policies... they won't load properly.

Is there a way to remove the "/agents" from the URLs without messing up the rest of our application? I could shorten it to "/a/:id but that ends up being more confusing than it's worth.

Thanks!

EDIT: a couple of people have mentioned solutions that work when the agent id is a number. That's a great idea except that we have built agent "slugs" to use instead.

On the agent website layout:

```
created() {
    console.log(this.$route.params.id);
    this.$store.dispatch("getAgentFromSlug", this.$route.params.id);
  }
```

and in the store:

```
getAgentFromSlug({commit}, payload){
  const db = firebase.database();
  db.ref("users/").orderByChild("slug").equalTo(payload).once("value", 
(snap) => {
    console.log(snap.val());
    var info = snap.val();
    commit("setAgentSiteInfo", info[Object.keys(info)[0]])
  })
}
```

So, our route Id is really a slug.

Comment: How's the format of those slugs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering `id`s are numbers, you could use:

```
{
  path: '/:id(\\d+)',
  name: 'AgentSite',
  component: AgentSite
},
```

Which only matches if `id` is made only of numbers.

> **Update:** A couple of people have mentioned solutions that work when the agent id is a number. That's a great idea except that we have built agent "slugs" to use instead.

If the names can conflict with existing routes, **declare the agent route last**.

From the [**Matching Priority** docs](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#matching-priority) (emphasis mine):

> ## Matching Priority
>
> Sometimes the same URL may be matched by multiple routes. In such a
>   case the matching priority is determined by the order of route
>   definition: **the earlier a route is defined, the higher priority it
>   gets**.

In other words, declare like:

```js
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: HomePage
    },
    {
      path: '/quotes',
      component: Quotes
    },
    {
      path: '/clients',
      component: Clients
    },
    {
      path: '/:id',
      component: AgentSite,
      props: true
    }
  ]
```

See **[CodeSandbox demo Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kokoqxvl87?module=%2Frouter%2Findex.js)**.

## Handling 404 pages

> Would I then declare the 404 page route above or below the "`AgentSite`" in your example? `{ path: "*", component: PageNotFound }`

The `AgentSite` route would **match any URL not matched previously**, so you'll have to handle the 404s inside the `AgentSite` component.

First, declare the 404 route **after** the `AgentSite`:

```js
  routes: [
    // ... (other routes)
    {
      path: "/:id",
      component: AgentSite,
      props: true
    },
    {
      path: ":path",
      name: "404",
      component: p404,
      props: true
    }
  ]
```

Then, inside `AgentSite`, get the agent `:id`, check if it is a known agent and, if not, redirect to the `404` route **by name** (otherwise it would match agent again).

```js
export default {
  props: ["id"],
  data() {
    return {
      availableAgents: ["scully", "bond", "nikita"]
    };
  },
  created() {
    let isExistingAgent = this.availableAgents.includes(this.id);
    if (!isExistingAgent) {
      this.$router.push({
        name: "404",
        params: { path: this.$route.fullPath.substring(1) }
      });
    }
  }
};
```

The **[CodeSandbox demo Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kokoqxvl87?module=%2Frouter%2Findex.js)** already contains this handling.

Comment: Thanks for the idea... I edited the original post to show how the actual URL uses a slug instead of an Id

Comment: Awesome thank you! Quick question on the 404 page... would I then declare this above or below the "AgentSite" in your example?  `{ path: "*", component: PageNotFound }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex matching if you `:id` has a specific format ([example from vue-router repository](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/route-matching/app.js)).

For example, if your `:id` is a number:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/:id(\\d+)', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]
```

```js
const Foo = { template: '<div>foo</div>' }
const Bar = { template: '<div>bar</div>' }

const routes = [
  { path: '/:id(\\d+)', component: Foo },
  { path: '/bar', component: Bar }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
.router-link-active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>Hello App!</h1>
  <p>
    <router-link to="/321321">Go to Foo</router-link>
    <router-link to="/bar">Go to Bar</router-link>
  </p>

  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea... I edited the original post to show how the actual URL uses a slug instead of an Id

Comment: Well, I anticipated that you are using a slug, so I tried to search solution. I found that `^(?!contact|about-us).*` regex (https://regexr.com/3ml3d) would work, but vue.js uses pillarjs/path-to-regex library to match these regexes and group matches are problematic. It's not possible. Look at https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/issues/95.