# How to redirect non-dynamic urls with vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

We have a vue.js app for an insurance company where every agent has their own dynamically-generated website. Currently, if you visit a gibberish link, it will show the blank agent template. We need urls that don't include an agent's slug to redirect to our "NotFound" component.

Below is our vue-router code if there happens to be an easy fix. Otherwise is it easier to add a computed function to redirect a visitor if, for example, the agent.name == null?

Thanks for any help!

Example of a good url: https://my.piaselect.com/georgebeach

Example of a bad url: https://my.piaselect.com/georgebeach2

Our router:

```
{
  path: "/:id",
  component: AgentSite,
  name: 'AgentSite',
  props: true
},
{
    path: '*',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: NotFound
}
```

Comment: the key is how do you know whether an agent id is valid or not

Answer (score 1):

Building on what @Jacob Goh has said.

You need a way to to now if the agent id is valid or not. Let's assume you have a list of agent id's, you can use a route guard to block the route to invalid ids.

https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to get the general idea.

```
const agentIds = ['Bob', 'Michael']

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo:id',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (agentIds.includes(to.params.id)) {
          // The agent is fine - continue
          next();
        } else {
          // doesn't exist - go back to root or any other page
          next({ path: '/' });
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: This would work except in this scenario, there will be ew agents joining all the time. The ID's will always be changing. Is there a way to achieve the same thing be checking to see if the id is null?

Comment: In my example, I used an array as an example. I would think that you would request the agent data from elsewhere, like from a db or server. This would keep it in sync with new agents.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work because you don't specify any name in this path :

```
{
  path: "/:id",
  component: AgentSite,
  name: 'AgentSite',
  props: true
},
```

because of that, this path allow any random chars at the root to return the component `AgentSite` (but blank because the random chars "param" fit to nothing in the component i guess).

To prevent that, you can specify a name to your path : `path: "agent/:id"` for example.

**Edit** : it seems you already had a great solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49416554/9541423)...